# Is it possible to give analytical solution to this equation?

Tags: systems-of-equations

Given three angles $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3\in[0,2\pi)$, and a non-zero constant $K\in\mathbb{R}$, is it possible to solve the following equations analytically?
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      \sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)+\sin(\theta_1-\theta_3)=K\sin(2\theta_1)\\
      \sin(\theta_2-\theta_1)+\sin(\theta_2-\theta_3)=K\sin(2\theta_2)\\
\sin(\theta_3-\theta_1)+\sin(\theta_3-\theta_2)=K\sin(2\theta_3)\\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Note that when $K=0$ it can be easily solved.